AAD roles on Postgres flexible server
Happy Friday, fellow IT people!
I am creating infrastructure for Azure Postgres flexible server along the roles required for authentication via terraform. Below is the contents of my main.tf file:
data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

module "naming_azurerm_resource_group" {
  source        = "git::https://dev.azure.com/companyname/Engineering/_git/terraform-naming//src?ref=1.0.14"
  resource_type = "azurerm_resource_group"
  name          = "companyname-postgresql-flexible"
  environment   = var.environment_name
  location      = var.location
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "main" {
  name     = module.naming_azurerm_resource_group.name
  location = var.location
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "admin_username" {
  name         = "postgresql-flexible-server-user-name"
  key_vault_id = var.key_vault_id
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "admin_password" {
  name         = "postgresql-flexible-server-user-password"
  key_vault_id = var.key_vault_id
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "postgresql_server_group_object_id" {
  name         = "postgresql-flexible-server-group-object-id"
  key_vault_id = var.key_vault_id
}

module "naming_azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server" {
  source        = "git::https://dev.azure.com/companyname/Engineering/_git/terraform-naming//src?ref=1.0.14"
  resource_type = "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server"
  name          = "companyname"
  environment   = var.environment_name
  location      = var.location
}

resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server" "main" {
  name                   = module.naming_azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.name
  resource_group_name    = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  location               = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  administrator_login    = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.admin_username.value
  administrator_password = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.admin_password.value
  depends_on             = [azurerm_resource_group.main]
  zone                   = 2

  authentication {
    active_directory_auth_enabled = "true"
    password_auth_enabled         = "true"
    tenant_id                     = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  }

  backup_retention_days        = var.backup_retention_days
  geo_redundant_backup_enabled = "true"

  high_availability {
    mode                      = "ZoneRedundant"
    standby_availability_zone = 1

  }

  identity {
    type         = "UserAssigned"
    identity_ids = [var.identity_ids]
  }

  sku_name   = var.sku_name
  storage_mb = var.storage_mb
  version    = 16
  auto_grow_enabled = "true"
  tags = azurerm_resource_group.main.tags
}

resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server_configuration" "main" {
  name      = "azure.extensions"
  server_id = azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.main.id
  value     = "CITEXT,HSTORE,UUID-OSSP,plpgsql,pg_stat_statements,pg_buffercache"
}

resource "null_resource" "roles_setup" {
  triggers = {
    always_run = formatdate("YYYYMMDD", timestamp())
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
      sudo apt install postgresql
      export PGPASSWORD=$(az account get-access-token --resource-type oss-rdbms --query "[accessToken]" -o tsv)
      psql -h ${azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.main.name}.postgres.database.azure.com -p 5432 -U ${var.principal_name} -d postgres -f create_server_roles_${var.environment_name}.psql
      EOT
  }
  depends_on = [azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server_firewall_rule.main["allow-azure-services"]]
}

resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server_active_directory_administrator" "main" {
  server_name         = azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.main.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  tenant_id           = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id           = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.postgresql_server_group_object_id.value
  principal_name      = var.principal_name
  principal_type      = "Group"
}

resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server_firewall_rule" "main" {
  for_each         = { for rule in var.fw_rules : rule.name => rule }
  name             = each.value.name
  server_id        = azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.main.id
  start_ip_address = each.value.start_ip_address
  end_ip_address   = each.value.end_ip_address
  depends_on       = [azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server_active_directory_administrator.main]
}

resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server_firewall_rule" "main_aws_vnet_ip" {
  name             = "aws-vnet-ip"
  server_id        = azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.main.id
  start_ip_address = var.aws_ip
  end_ip_address   = var.aws_ip
}

resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server" "replica" {
  count                  = var.environment_name == "prod" ? 1 : 0
  name                   = "${var.environment_name}-${var.replica_location}-companyname-psqlf-replica"
  resource_group_name    = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  location               = var.replica_location
  create_mode            = "Replica"
  source_server_id       = azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.main.id
  administrator_login    = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.admin_username.value
  administrator_password = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.admin_password.value

  authentication {
    active_directory_auth_enabled = "true"
    password_auth_enabled         = "true"
    tenant_id                     = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  }

  backup_retention_days = var.backup_retention_days

  identity {
    type         = "UserAssigned"
    identity_ids = [var.identity_ids]
  }

  sku_name   = var.sku_name
  storage_mb = var.storage_mb
  auto_grow_enabled = "true"
  tags = azurerm_resource_group.main.tags

  depends_on = [azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.main]
}

resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server_configuration" "replica" {
  count     = var.environment_name == "prod" ? 1 : 0
  name      = "azure.extensions"
  server_id = azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.replica[0].id
  value     = "CITEXT,HSTORE,UUID-OSSP"
}

resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server_firewall_rule" "replica" {
  for_each         = var.environment_name == "prod" ? { for rule in var.fw_rules : rule.name => rule } : {}
  name             = each.value.name
  server_id        = azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.replica[0].id
  start_ip_address = each.value.start_ip_address
  end_ip_address   = each.value.end_ip_address
}

resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server_firewall_rule" "replica_aws_vnet_ip" {
  count            = var.environment_name == "prod" ? 1 : 0
  name             = "aws-vnet-ip"
  server_id        = azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.replica[0].id
  start_ip_address = var.aws_ip
  end_ip_address   = var.aws_ip
}

The trigger in the null data source is there to be able to replace the script in case it doesn't work, just for debugging. When it goes live, it will be transformed into terraform data resource without the trigger.
There are 2 admin accounts on the server level: one account with password authentication and an Entra (AAD) Admin, which is actually an AAD group.
The script that creates the roles on the server was partially provided by chatGPT after multiple iterations:
DO $$
DECLARE
    db_array TEXT[];
    db_name TEXT;
    schema_name TEXT;
    role_name TEXT;
    aad_roles TEXT[] := ARRAY[
        'sql_postgres_dev_read_only',
        'sql_postgres_dev_read_insert',
        'sql_postgres_dev_read_insert_update',
        'sql_postgres_dev_insert',
        'sql_postgres_dev_full_access'
    ];
    user_roles TEXT[] := ARRAY[
        'analytics',
        'backup_user',
        'grafana',
        'qlik',
        'synapse'
    ];
BEGIN
    -- Step 1: Create user roles if they don't exist
    FOREACH role_name IN ARRAY user_roles
    LOOP
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname = role_name) THEN
            EXECUTE format('CREATE ROLE %I;', role_name);
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    -- Step 2: Create AAD roles if they don't exist
    FOREACH role_name IN ARRAY aad_roles
    LOOP
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname = role_name) THEN
            EXECUTE format('SELECT * FROM pgaadauth_create_principal(%L, false, false);', role_name);
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    -- Step 3: Fetch all databases except templates
    SELECT array_agg(datname)
    INTO db_array
    FROM pg_database
    WHERE datistemplate = false;

    -- Step 4: Loop through each database and grant privileges
    FOREACH db_name IN ARRAY db_array
    LOOP
        -- Check if db_name is properly referenced
        RAISE NOTICE 'Processing database: %', db_name;

        -- Grant CONNECT privilege to the database role
        EXECUTE format('GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE %I TO %I;', db_name, 'sql_postgres_dev_read_only');
        EXECUTE format('GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE %I TO %I;', db_name, 'sql_postgres_dev_read_insert');
        EXECUTE format('GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE %I TO %I;', db_name, 'sql_postgres_dev_insert');
        EXECUTE format('GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE %I TO %I;', db_name, 'sql_postgres_dev_read_insert_update');
        EXECUTE format('GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE %I TO %I;', db_name, 'sql_postgres_dev_full_access');
        
        -- Grant privileges on schemas and tables
        EXECUTE format('GRANT USAGE, CREATE ON SCHEMA public TO %I;', 'sql_postgres_dev_read_only');
        EXECUTE format('GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO %I;', 'sql_postgres_dev_read_only');

        EXECUTE format('GRANT USAGE, CREATE ON SCHEMA public TO %I;', 'sql_postgres_dev_read_insert');
        EXECUTE format('GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO %I;', 'sql_postgres_dev_read_insert');

        EXECUTE format('GRANT USAGE, CREATE ON SCHEMA public TO %I;', 'sql_postgres_dev_insert');
        EXECUTE format('GRANT INSERT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO %I;', 'sql_postgres_dev_insert');

        EXECUTE format('GRANT USAGE, CREATE ON SCHEMA public TO %I;', 'sql_postgres_dev_read_insert_update');
        EXECUTE format('GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO %I;', 'sql_postgres_dev_read_insert_update');

        EXECUTE format('GRANT USAGE, CREATE ON SCHEMA public TO %I;', 'sql_postgres_dev_full_access');
        EXECUTE format('GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO %I;', 'sql_postgres_dev_full_access');

        -- Grant privileges for standard user roles
        EXECUTE format('GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE %I TO analytics;', db_name);
        EXECUTE format('GRANT USAGE, CREATE ON SCHEMA public TO analytics;');
        EXECUTE format('GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO analytics;');

        EXECUTE format('GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE %I TO backup_user;', db_name);
        EXECUTE format('GRANT USAGE, CREATE ON SCHEMA public TO backup_user;');
        EXECUTE format('GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO backup_user;');

        EXECUTE format('GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE %I TO grafana;', db_name);
        EXECUTE format('GRANT USAGE, CREATE ON SCHEMA public TO grafana;');
        EXECUTE format('GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO grafana;');

        EXECUTE format('GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE %I TO qlik;', db_name);
        EXECUTE format('GRANT USAGE, CREATE ON SCHEMA public TO qlik;');
        EXECUTE format('GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO qlik;');

        EXECUTE format('GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE %I TO synapse;', db_name);
        EXECUTE format('GRANT USAGE, CREATE ON SCHEMA public TO synapse;');
        EXECUTE format('GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO synapse;');
    END LOOP;
END
$$;

Even though the script is ran as the AAD Admin with an access token, after the script runs, the permissions are not created, I'm getting this output:
null_resource.roles_setup (local-exec): psql:create_server_roles_dev.psql:95: NOTICE:  Processing database: database_1
null_resource.roles_setup (local-exec): psql:create_server_roles_dev.psql:95: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "database_1"
null_resource.roles_setup (local-exec): psql:create_server_roles_dev.psql:95: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "database_1"
null_resource.roles_setup (local-exec): psql:create_server_roles_dev.psql:95: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "database_1"
null_resource.roles_setup (local-exec): psql:create_server_roles_dev.psql:95: WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "database_1"
...

I've been trying to fix this for over a day, thought I might be missing some permissions on the AAD Admin role, logged in as regular admin and for each DB and Schema ran the following commands:
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE database_1 TO "aad_admin_role_name";
\c database_1
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO "aad_admin_role_name";

That didn't change anything. Please help, I'm desperate to get this working. I would really prefer to avoid logging in to the server and creating permissions for each role on each DB and each schema manually. Will be happy to answer any questions. Cheers!

Can you please check that AAD Admin has GRANT privilege on all databases and also has both GRANT and CREATE privileges on all schemas correctly assigned @EvgeniiFedosov


AAD roles on Postgres flexible server using terraform

The issue seems to be privilages that azure_pg_admin lacks. According to the documention  follow the steps below
CREATE ROLE elevated_admin WITH LOGIN CREATEDB CREATEROLE PASSWORD 'YourPassword';

Reassign ownership of existing databases and schemas to the new role
ALTER DATABASE your_database OWNER TO elevated_admin;
ALTER SCHEMA public OWNER TO elevated_admin;

Demo configruation:
resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server" "main" {
  name                   = var.server_name
  resource_group_name    = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  location               = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  administrator_login    = var.admin_username
  administrator_password = var.admin_password
  version                = "13"
  storage_mb             = var.storage_mb
  sku_name               = var.sku_name
  backup_retention_days  = var.backup_retention_days
  zone                   = "1"
  

  authentication {
    active_directory_auth_enabled = true
    password_auth_enabled         = true
    tenant_id                     = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  }

  identity {
    type         = "UserAssigned"
    identity_ids = var.identity_ids
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = var.environment_name
  }
}

resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server_active_directory_administrator" "main" {
  server_name         = azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.main.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  tenant_id           = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id           = var.aad_admin_object_id
  principal_name      = var.aad_admin_principal_name
  principal_type      = "Group"
}

resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server_firewall_rule" "main" {
  for_each         = { for rule in var.fw_rules : rule.name => rule }
  name             = each.value.name
  server_id        = azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.main.id
  start_ip_address = each.value.start_ip_address
  end_ip_address   = each.value.end_ip_address
}

resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server_firewall_rule" "aws_vnet_ip" {
  name             = "aws-vnet-ip"
  server_id        = azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.main.id
  start_ip_address = var.aws_ip
  end_ip_address   = var.aws_ip
}

resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server" "replica" {
  count                  = var.environment_name == "prod" ? 1 : 0
  name                   = "${var.environment_name}-${var.replica_location}-${var.server_name}-replica"
  resource_group_name    = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  location               = var.replica_location
  create_mode            = "Replica"
  source_server_id       = azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.main.id
  administrator_login    = var.admin_username
  administrator_password = var.admin_password

  authentication {
    active_directory_auth_enabled = true
    password_auth_enabled         = true
    tenant_id                     = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  }

  identity {
    type         = "UserAssigned"
    identity_ids = var.identity_ids
  }

  sku_name   = var.sku_name
  storage_mb = var.storage_mb

  tags = {
    Environment = var.environment_name
  }

  depends_on = [azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.main]
}

Deployment:

Refer:
azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server_active_directory_administrator | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform | Terraform Registry
